# AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Rails app using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and there are two env; Dev-env and Prod-env. However, Dev-env gives me "production" when I do Rails.env. Also, log file is defined as /var/app/current/log/production.log not /var/app/current/log/development.log in Dev-env. Am i missing something?

Here is my .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml file.

`branch-defaults:
  develop:
    environment: Dev-env
  master:
    environment: Prod-env
environment-defaults:
  Dev-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  ...`

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html#create_deploy_Ruby_rails-devenv has a good walkthrough

Comment: What is the environment variable `RACK_ENV` set to on your environments? `config.yml` just maps git branches to EB environments, but you'll need to actually tell Rails what the environments are called.